# GCM XMPP on Appengine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Google just announced a new api for GCM to IO13 that using the xmpp protocol.  Is it possible to use this api with appengine?  It does not look like it would work with appengine's XMPP support, but perhaps with the new Sockets api.  Can this be done from a frontend, backend, or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with current GAE XMPP support. The problem is user/server addressing: GAE XMPP API sends messages to users defined by email addresses. It then performs a DNS lookup for the XMPP server SRV record (e.g. dig srv _xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com +short to look up the XMPP servers for @gmail.com addresses). This is not how GCM CCS works - you have to connect to fixed server.

OTOH, you could use Outgoing Socket API and then implement XMPP protocol.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I thought that was the case. I would be interested in seeing this work with the Socket Api.  Any one know examples or have implemented this themselves?  Of course this would take a backend instance to have long running connections.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Messaging Team told me:
'Google App Engine does not currently support connections to CCS.'

I was looking at the source code of the simple python-xmpp, 
it looks pretty easy to port to App Engine, it only need python dns,
there is no other third-party library requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Only XMPP endpoints GCM Cloud Connection Server needs XMPP support when you want to stream your message. If AppEngine doesn't support XMPP, you can use older GCM HTTP messaging instead. Only HTTP POST requests are needed to send message to your device.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is not really useful.  Appengine is a little different from a traditional server environmet.  It does support XMPP messages, but don't have any experience with it.  I am aware of the HTTP messaging and am currently using it.